# Java Swing Window will not appear

Tags: java, swing

Ok guys, here comes the humility. It's been a long time since I used Java Swing so I know there is some really obvious solution to this problem. What I'm trying to do is get all of these various swing elements to appear in a window. When I run the code, nothing happens. I don't see anything at all. Every time I google the answer I get stuff about various complicated JPanel problems and I'm almost positive this isn't a difficult issue. So here's my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;


public class LimoSysDriver extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    JLabel title = new JLabel("Thread Test Application");

    JLabel numOne = new JLabel("1");
    JLabel numTwo = new JLabel("2");
    JLabel numThr = new JLabel("3");
    JLabel numFou = new JLabel("4");

    JProgressBar progOne = new JProgressBar();
    JProgressBar progTwo = new JProgressBar();
    JProgressBar progThr = new JProgressBar();
    JProgressBar progFou = new JProgressBar();

    JLabel counterOne = new JLabel(Integer.toString(progOne.getValue()));
    JLabel counterTwo = new JLabel(Integer.toString(progTwo.getValue()));
    JLabel counterThr = new JLabel(Integer.toString(progThr.getValue()));
    JLabel counterFou = new JLabel(Integer.toString(progFou.getValue()));

    JLabel numGrandTot = new JLabel("Grand Total");
    JLabel counterTot = new JLabel();

    JButton start = new JButton();
    JButton pause = new JButton();
    JButton resume = new JButton();


    public LimoSysDriver(){
        setSize(700,300);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        add(pane);
        JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel();
        lowerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(lowerPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        add(lowerPanel);

        pane.add(title);
        pane.add(numOne);
        pane.add(progOne);
        pane.add(counterOne);

        pane.add(numTwo);
        pane.add(progTwo);
        pane.add(counterTwo);

        pane.add(numThr);
        pane.add(progThr);
        pane.add(counterThr);

        pane.add(numFou);
        pane.add(progFou);
        pane.add(counterFou);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LimoSysDriver window = new LimoSysDriver();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The problem is, the window doesn't show up at all. Once I can get that sorted out, I'll be able to troubleshoot the rest of it. Thanks in advance everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it to visible. Use:

```
setVisible(true)
```

Comment: Make sure you do it towards the end, after you have added everything to the pane you want to display

Answer (score 3):

Some tips:

- Need to make visible your `JFrame` calling [setVisible(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29)
- Instead of `add(pane)` you can use `setContentPane(pane)` replacing the default container used as content pane.
- Don't forget to call [pack()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) method when you finish adding components and before making your `JFrame` visible..
- Create your GUI objects in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) using [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)
- Avoid extend from `JFrame` unless you need to add some functionality. If that's not the case, use a `JFrame` variable or class member instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've been told to use SwingUtilities before. May I ask why? What the advantage is? I'm sure you're correct. I just want to understand more completely. Also, does this approach allow you to designate specific threads for each object? I want to have a thread for each progress bar but I haven't been able to get it to work. ------ Nevermind! I'm reading the APIs now and I understand. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Swing components should be always created an updated in a single special thread called Event Dispatch Thread. This is necessary because most Swing object methods are not "thread safe". About progress bar I'd suggest you use [SwingWorker](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/) which provides methods to make a long task in a background thread and update Swing components (progress bar) in the EDT.

Comment: You're welcome! :-) Another tip: be aware that Event process take place in EDT. For instance the code within `actionPerformed()` method will take place in EDT. If you execute a long task (query a database, download a file, send an email) in that method, then your GUI may "freeze" waiting this task finishes. This is good case for use SwingWorker, doing that kind of tasks in background (in a separate thread).